# Recursively listing all subdirectory of a given directory

Tags: c, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I have to recursively list all the subdirectories of a given directory and I got it working, but it lists them out of order.  I want it to list all the subdirectories of the given directory and then move on to the next subdirectory and I know it's because my recursion is inside the while loop, but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement it outside the loop.  I thought about making an array of strings with the paths of the subdirectory and use it as a stack, but after looking it up, I don't think that is possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int listDir(char *name)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *cDir;

    dir = opendir(name);
    if(dir != NULL)
    {
        while((cDir=readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            char* subName = cDir->d_name;       
            if(strcmp(subName, ".")==0 || strcmp(subName, "..")==0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                //  Checks if it's a directory
                if(cDir->d_type == DT_DIR)        
                {
                    printf("%s\n", subName);
                    char *path;
                    path = malloc(sizeof(name) + sizeof(subName) + 2);
                    strcat(path, name);
                    strcat(path, "/");
                    strcat(path, subName);
                    listDir(path);                  
                }   
            }
        }


        closedir(dir);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    listDir(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code already explores children depth first. Did you want breadth-first search? Could you provide examples showing what it currently does and the desired behavior? Also, I recommend compiling with `-Wall` always and freeing memory. `sizeof(name)` doesn't allocate the memory you think it does, either--that's just the pointer, not the whole string. Using valgrind or asan can help find these issues.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to print this in the a breadth first search fashion, but you are right I'm searching in a depth first search method and I don't know how to implement the recursion so that it does it in a breadth first search.

Directory: test->test2. test5
                 test2->test6

Desired output:
test
test2
test5
test6

My output: 
test
test2
test6
test5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the directory structure in a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), you could use a queue. Since C doesn't have such a thing in its standard library, you have to roll your own or use a library. Here's a simple example of how this might work, alongside a cleaned up version of your DFS.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void listDirBFS(char *name)
{
    int q_front = 0;
    int q_back = 1;
    int q_cap = 4;
    char **q = malloc(q_cap * sizeof(*q));

    for (q[0] = strdup(name); q_front != q_back;) 
    {
        name = q[q_front++];
        DIR *dir = opendir(name);

        if (!dir) continue;

        printf("%s\n", name);
        size_t name_len = strlen(name);
        struct dirent *cDir;

        while ((cDir = readdir(dir)))
        {
            char *subName = cDir->d_name;

            if (strcmp(subName, ".") && strcmp(subName, "..") &&
                cDir->d_type == DT_DIR)
            {
                char *path = malloc(name_len + strlen(subName) + 2);
                sprintf(path, "%s/%s", name, subName);

                if (q_back >= q_cap && 
                    !(q = realloc(q, sizeof(*q) * (q_cap *= 2)))) 
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d realloc\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                    exit(1);
                }

                q[q_back++] = path;
            }
        }

        free(name);         
        closedir(dir);
    }

    free(q);
}

void listDir(char *name)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(name);

    if (!dir) return;

    printf("%s\n", name);
    size_t name_len = strlen(name);
    struct dirent *cDir;

    while ((cDir = readdir(dir)))
    {
        char *subName = cDir->d_name;

        if (strcmp(subName, ".") && strcmp(subName, "..") &&
            cDir->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            char *path = malloc(name_len + strlen(subName) + 2);
            sprintf(path, "%s/%s", name, subName);
            listDir(path);
            free(path);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    puts("== DFS ==");
    listDir(".");
    puts("\n== BFS ==");
    listDirBFS(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
== DFS ==
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/e
./a/bb
./a/bb/f
./a/bb/f/g
./aa
./aa/c
./aaa
./aaa/d
./aaa/d/h
./aaa/d/hh

== BFS ==
.
./a
./aa
./aaa
./a/b
./a/bb
./aa/c
./aaa/d
./a/b/e
./a/bb/f
./aaa/d/h
./aaa/d/hh
./a/bb/f/g
```

A few remarks and suggestions on your code:

- `sizeof(name) + sizeof(subName)` is incorrect. `sizeof` returns the size of the pointers; `strlen` is probably what you intended to get the lengths of the pointed-to strings. This avoids undefined behavior due to possibly `strcat`-ing beyond the allocated memory.
- Always `free` memory after use to avoid memory leaks.
- Compiling with the `-Wall` flag to turn warnings on reveals that control reaches the end of a non-void function. Change your return type from `int` to `void` if you're not actually returning an integer.
- Note that I changed where the prints occur. You can move them back to the location of the recursive call, but I prefer to do the work for each node at the top of the function before exploring children. The algorithms are fundamentally the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll study your code, try to implement it into my program tomorrow and let you know how it goes! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Also, thank you for the strelen suggestion and the reminder to free up my memory, I always forget to do that... lol bad habit, but I'll definitely work on it

Comment: I'd open a new question with your updated code--it's hard to follow the new problem. You can link to this thread/post for context. BTW, BFS is really unnatural to describe recursively... it's almost always done with a queue, but recursion uses a stack, so your problem seems to boil down to simulating a BFS with a stack. Is there a particular reason why your BFS needs to be recursive?

Comment: I got it working! Yeah I didn't know how it was going to work recursively since I thought queues were a little iffy, but in the end it ended up working :D.  I had to implement your BFS function recursively because it was part of the requirements.  

I just want to say thank you so much for your help and I couldn't have done it without you!

Answer (score 1):

> I have to recursively list all the subdirectories of a given directory

Please notice that [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) are unknown to the C11 standard or previous ones (some [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) operating systems in the previous century did not have any directories, but did had a C compiler; and [VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) had a different notion of directory than the OS running on your computer; AFAIK an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) is programmable in C but usually has no [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) at all). Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). The API related to directories is [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) specific. On Windows it would be the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

On Linux systems, you should use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html); it will do most of the work for you; it is part of [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/) whose source code is freely available. Or consider libraries such as [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) if you can use C++) and study their source code.

You would pass to `nftw` some function which fills (and/or [realloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html)) some global or `static` pointer to a `struct`  *carefully defined by you*, perhaps ending with some [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Notice that [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You could **study its source code for inspiration.**

Notice that [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/) has a builtin `find` command and is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source). You could study its source code for inspiration.

And the [`zsh` shell](https://zsh.org/)  (also the [`fish` shell](https://fishshell.com/)) has powerful shell expansion facilities, including recursive [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) like `ls **/*.c` so you could study its source code for inspiration.

You are **incorrectly coding**:

> ```
>                path = malloc(sizeof(name) + sizeof(subName) + 2);
>                strcat(path, name);
> ```

but it is wrong ([undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)) since [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) can fail and you should test that and you did not (remember that [strcat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) expects a valid destination).

Please **read *quickly* [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**. On Linux, compile your code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn to use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for all the resources you've linked.  I'll definitely take a look at them over the summer and the next time I code! And also I appreciate your explanation on malloc, I'll be sure to avoid that in the future

Comment: Don't look at the resources next week. Look at them *today*; you'll learn *a lot* by reading existing source code !!!

Comment: Unfortunately, deadlines are coming close and finals are around the corner so I don't feel like I have to do so right, but I will in the future!